# SQL Error: ORA-00971: missing SET keyword

Tags: sql, oracle

I am getting below error

> Error at Command Line : 1 Column : 29
>   Error report -
>   SQL Error: ORA-00971: missing SET keyword
>   00971. 00000 -  "missing SET keyword"

Please help me to solve this

here is the query that i used

```
update siebel.S_LOY_MEMBER a,siebel.s_contact b,siebel.s_contact_x c
SET
a.REC_PTNR_PROM_FLG ='N',
b.SUPPRESS_EMAIL_FLG ='Y',
b.SUPPRESS_FAX_FLG ='Y',
c.ATTRIB_09 ='Y'
where a.PR_CON_ID = b.par_row_id
and b.row_id = c.par_row_id
and a.PROGRAM_ID = '1-15P'
and a.REG_CHANNEL_CD ='Booking'
and a.MEM_NUM ='677609224'
```

Thanks
 Praveen

Comment: Oracle only allows you to update one table at a time, in an update statement.  One solution to your problem is multiple updates within a transaction.

Comment: It would also be possible to update child tables via triggers but I don't know whether that would be useful in this case.